# How to disable modules in EAP 6?

Tags: jboss, redhat, hornetq

I want to use RedHat EAP 6 for commercial support on HornetQ. Can't find anywhere how to disable every non-relevant module (e.g. EJB's etc).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You can remove a module using CLI in EAP 6(Only remove option is available not DISABLE option)

1. connect to CLI

   ```
      ./jboss-cli.sh
   ```
2. Remove modules(Press TAB to remove the required modules)

   ```
   module remove --name=system.layers.base.aaa.bbb.main.module.xml
   ```

Comment: Thanks. Will that be saved on file system or only on the currently running instance? I.e. will I need to re-apply this every time?